# Tools for doing a RESTful POST to multiple URLs

Tags: url, rest, post

Are there any tools that can hit multiple URLs with a POST request at the same time? I need it for doing some validation on many restful servers at once instead of 1 at a time for time sake.

Comment: That is not very clear. You ask if there are tools but you mention some - that implies that they do exist. Perhaps you should elaborate your need a bit further.

Comment: Fair enough. The above examples only let you post to 1 url at a time, instead of multiple urls at simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that http://jmeter.apache.org/ is sufficiently sound to accomplish what you need:
 - You can trigger multiple URLs at the same time
 - You can concurrently load a single URL with multiple requests
 - You can assess the response time
 - You can make assertion testing to check everything is OK.